# Norms on a Euclidean domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

A norm $N$ on a Euclidean Domain $R$ is a function $N:R \longrightarrow \{0,1,2,...\}$ such that

(i) $N(a) = 0 \longleftrightarrow a = 0$

(ii)$N(ab) = N(a)N(b)$

(iii) if $b \neq 0$, then $a=qb + r$ with $N(r) < N(b)$

Now i need to prove two things

(1) if $N(u) = 1 \longleftrightarrow u$ is a unit

(2) if $N(a)$ is prime in $Z$ then $a$ is irreducible

Here is my attempt for 1,

if $N(u)= 1$ then $N(ub) =N(u)N(b) = N(b)$ and so since $N(ub) = N(b)$ then $ub = b$ hence $u = 1$ which is a unit

But i can't derive the other implication , that is if $u$ is a unit , then there exists an element $b$ such that $ub = 1$ and so what ? Any suggestion here !

And for (2) I did it by contradiction (is it true)

Assume $N(a) = p$ where $p$ is prime, but $a$ is reducible, this means that
there exists $m,n$ such that $a =mn$ and so $N(a)= N(mn) = N(m)N(n) = p$ but now we can see that $N(m)$ and $N(n)$ are both integers and so $p$ is not prime .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1). $u$ is a unit $\Rightarrow$ there exists $v \in R$ such that $uv = 1 = vu.$ So $N(uv)= N(1) = 1 \Rightarrow N(u) = 1.$ On the other hand suppose $N(u) = 1.$ Then there exists $v, r \in R$ such that $1 = uv + r$ and $N(r) < N(u).$ The last condition implies that $r = 0.$ Hence $uv = 1 \Rightarrow u$ is a unit.

(2). Suppose $a = mn,$ for some $m, n \in R$ and $N(a)$ is a prime in $\mathbb Z.$ Now $N(a) = N(m)N(n) \Rightarrow$ at least one of $N(m), N(n)$ equals $1.$ Hence at least one of $m, n$ is a unit in $R.$